# Replace the 2 number in a file name to get the correct format in python

Tags: numbers

I have some kind of the file name:

Love Scene (2021) 01 TMP.mp4

Love.Scene.2021 02.TMP.mp4

Love.Scene.2021.03.TMP.mp4

LoveScene04.TMP.mp4

01, 02, 03, 04 is the episode number.

In a correct name, it should be:

Love Scene (2021) E01 TMP.mp4

Love.Scene.2021 E02.TMP.mp4

Love.Scene.2021.E03.TMP.mp4

LoveScene.E04.TMP.mp4

How to use Regular Expression to add "E" before the Episode number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the data in the **data.txt** file, then string replace using regular expression can be done in the following way.
Output will be generated in **output.txt**

```
import re


def replaceString(d, prefx='E'):
    val = re.findall(r'\d{2}\b', d)
    if(len(val) > 0):
        d = (prefx+val[-1]).join(d.rsplit(val[-1], 1))
        print(d)
    return d


def handleData():
    prefx="E"
    file1 = open('data.txt', 'r')
    file2 = open('output.txt','w+')

    for line in file1.readlines():
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        line=replaceString(line,prefx)
        file2.write(line)
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
handleData()
```

input data.txt:

```
Love Scene (2021) 01 TMP.mp4

Love.Scene.2021 02.TMP.mp4

Love.Scene.2021.03.TMP.mp4

LoveScene04.TMP.mp4
```

output:

```
Love Scene (2021) E01 TMP.mp4
Love.Scene.2021 E02.TMP.mp4
Love.Scene.2021.E03.TMP.mp4
LoveSceneE04.TMP.mp4
```

Comment: The script works perfectly. Just want to open the circumstance

Comment: If that solves then you may consider it as accepted answer.

Comment: Script works perfectly, just one more question: How to by pass the file name that already has Exx or SxxEyy (xx, yy is 2 digits) in the list? ex: LoveSence.S01E01.TMP.mp4 or LoveSence.E05.TMP.mp4. Thank you!

Comment: Updated answer, assign any value to 'prefx'

Comment: You need to play with regex pattern *(r'\d{2}\b', d)* to suit to different needs.

Comment: with the update, result is LoveSence.S01EE01.TMP.mp4
LoveSence.EE05.TMP.mp4 (double 'E').

Comment: You would have to manually change the **prefx** for appending different text and you would have to change the  pattern **\d{2}\b** as well for different patterns.